# Error while using zxing scanner on my android app

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am delevoping an android app and my main class code is like this.

But it shows error before starting camera. How can I solve this?

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);    //Barcode Scanner to scan for us
        }
    });
```

AND THIS IS MY STACKTRACE

```
09-02 13:54:51.659  20660-20660/com.mehdi.BarCodeScanner I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch Down
09-02 13:54:51.739  20660-20660/com.mehdi.BarCodeScanner I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP
09-02 13:55:06.919  20660-20660/com.mehdi.BarCodeScanner D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-02 13:55:06.919  20660-20660/com.mehdi.BarCodeScanner W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41813e48)
09-02 13:55:06.949  20660-20660/com.mehdi.BarCodeScanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mehdi.BarCodeScanner, PID: 20660
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3468)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3429)
        at com.mehdi.BarCodeScanner.main$2.onClick(main.java:106)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: :Try out with adding permission of CAMERA in Android Manifest.

Comment: i did it like this  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> but i have error again

Comment: lets try this tutorial http://karanbalkar.com/2013/12/tutorial-65-implement-barcode-scanner-using-zxing-in-android/..hope it helps.

Comment: bro! follow this post http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162

Comment: Which error? Could you share the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN }

You need to install the ZXing application before trying to use it via `Intent`.

Consider using the [`IntentIntegrator`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent) approach to automate checking for and installing the ZXIng app.

Comment: i dont want to install that, because this is an application for a specefic work andwe cant use another app for this, plz help to do without thAT

Comment: Then you need deeper integration of some barcode scanner library. That's too broad to address in comments, though.